# Is it possible to find all paths between minimum and maximum cost in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, dijkstra

I have a neo4j database with around 10 million nodes. They are connected through relationships with a property "`weight`". I want to find the paths between a starting node and the target node based on the minimum and maximum cost (through "`weight`" property). I am using Java so I have explored `GraphAlgoFactory` and `Dijkstra` classes. Dijkstra will only give me multiple paths but with the minimum cost. But I want multiple paths which cost higher than the cost of shortest path.

Lets say there are multiple paths between two nodes `A` and `B`. The cost of minimum path is `20` (with 4 nodes). But I want all paths with cost `25` to `30`. Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Java, but you can aggregate data from a path in Cypher.

You first `MATCH` the start and end node with `[*1..n]` relationships and then `RETURN` all paths and the aggregated (i.e. reduced) weights on the relationships in this path.

Something along this line:

```
MATCH path = (a:Node {some: 'property'})-[*1..10]-(b:Node {some: 'property'})
RETURN path, reduce(sum = 0, r IN relationships(path) | sum + r.weight) AS weight_sum
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-reduce

Comment: I experimented with this approach but its too slow if there are thousands of paths in total. I only want paths of specific weight which are lot less than total number of paths. I am not sure if there is a way to eliminate paths quickly while traversing them which are not eligible for the end result.